# Uploading objects to Cloudant using NodeJS in Bluemix

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I'm trying to save the JSON from the GET request to an object and then upload the object to the Cloudant DB
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
var request = require("request");
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var body = new EventEmitter();
var sample = cloudant.db.use('sample')

request("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/gateway/ipsSearch.jsp?cs=IBM&hc=1000&rs=1001", function(error, response, data) {
body.data = data;
body.emit('update');
sample.insert({ crazy: true }, body.data, function(err, body, header{
 // hmm
});
console.log('hmm');
});
```

Comment: What's your error? Please post it. It looks like your request is not valid and has spaces in it. What are you trying to do? (You can't upload a JSON document with a GET request.)

Comment: @joe- Fixed the url. I'm trying to save the JSON to an object using the request and then upload the object to the Cloudant DB. Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have a male formatted URL for the request. And the code for inserting in cloudant data base is wrong written:

```
var request = require("request");
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var body = new EventEmitter();
var sample = cloudant.db.use('sample')

request("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/gateway/ipsSearch.jsp?cs=IBM&hc=1000&rs=1001", function(error, response, data) {
        body.data = data;
        body.emit('update');
//implement code for inserting in cloudant db for homework
});
```